# A single code to round the number of decimal places in the output

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, decimal

Is there a single code that I can write in the beginning of a file so that all numbers in the output are rounded to a specific number of decimal places?

So for example, let's say I have

```
print(7.18*9.39832)
print(3.134235*4.23534546)
print(8.7239847234+5.2342345436)
```

The output looks like

```
67.4799376
13.274567977823098
13.958219267
```

Is there a single code/function that I can write in the beginning so that I get, for instance, the following output

```
67.48
13.27
13.96
```

Answer (score 1):

round() function can help you:

```
round(67.4799376,2)
```

(First place is for your number & second place is for number of digits you want to be shown)

returns:

```
67.48
```

Comment: Thanks, but I will would have to do that individually for each number, right? I was looking for a single function or code that would round all the outputs, without having to write that function each time.

Comment: You can do that easily by using lists. You can find more information about list here:https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: I could do that but what I wrote in the question is just an example. What if I have a big file where making one list out of everything is simply not realistic. So I guess there isn't anything similar to what I'm looking for?

Comment: Maybe if you come up with what you have tried already  it will be easier to provide you with a better solution. But anyway if you are working with a big file a proper function can do what you want.

Comment: I haven't tried since I don't have a clue if its even possible. Anyways, thanks for the answer :) ... I guess there is no such thing.